# Reactive(Cocoa) or otherwise approach to mapping a producer whose map function depends on another producer

Tags: ios, reactive-programming, reactive-cocoa, reactive-cocoa-3

Apologies if this is a very basic question but I am a bit mentally stuck. I could probably proceed by cheating - introducing a `foreach`-style loop or something - but it would defeat the purpose.

I am learning `ReactiveCocoa` in particular and the concept in general.

I want to make an `AnnotationView` with a single `UITextView` that displays an `NSAttributedString` built from an `AnnotationViewModel` consisting of `annotatedText: String` and `annotationTags: [AnnotationTags]`.

The `AnnotationTags` in turn is really a collection of all the `AnnotationOccurrence`s for a specific label. For instance, if we annotated the word "the," we'd probably end up with many `AnnotationOccurrences` but just one tag for the word "the."

```
class DocumentAnalysisViewModel {

    let propertyText: MutableProperty<String>
    let propertyTags: MutableProperty<[AnnotationTagViewModel]>

    init(_ text: String, _ tags: [AnnotationTagViewModel]) {
        self.propertyText = MutableProperty(text)
        self.propertyTags = MutableProperty(tags)
    }

}
```

Anyway...

The way that an `AnnotationOccurrence` is defined - by start/end indices (just one pair) - tightly marries the `Occurrence` with the `annotatedText`.

So, to format the `NSAttributedString`, I need the `AnnotationTags,` and so in turn I need the `annotatedText` at the same time I am providing the tags.

This little problem has exposed my lack of depth in understanding ReactiveCocoa and this pattern in general. I tried doing the following, but stopped midway or earlier each time for various reasons:

- `vm.propertyTags.producer.combineLatestWith(vm.propertyText.producer)` -obviously won't compile without a `map` taking each to a common format, say, a tuple of `(String, [AnnotationViewModel])` - **I stopped because it felt clumsy and wrong.**
- Mapping the entire object or creating a `MutableProperty` for the entire object (the `DocumentAnalysisViewModel`) - **again, felt wrong, because even if it is better in this case, I am not learning how to handle what is surely a common need in Reactive design)

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Why does the first approach feel wrong to you? That would be my approach, if I'm understanding the problem correctly.

Comment: combineLatest is usually followed by a map, this is not wrong.